# How to print UIView.transform on live lldb console

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

Tried:`po (CGAffineTransform)[pinch.view transform]`

but saying

`error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.`

however

`(lldb) po (CGRect)[pinch.view frame]
(origin = (x = 16, y = 96), size = (width = 343, height = 500))
 (origin = (x = 16, y = 96), size = (width = 343, height = 500))`

can work.

Comment: is there any specific reason of using PO?

Comment: no, but you can use whatever it can print

Comment: Who just down vote this quesiton? I don't know why but if you had anything to say or debate, just leave comment rather than down vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(self.view.transform));`

Comment: Just updated my answer.. Try this.. I can see the output like [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] at my end..

Comment: Not working... (lldb) po NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(pinch.view.transform));
error: property 'transform' not found on object of type 'UIView *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

Comment: Try this... NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGAffineTransform([[self view] transform])

Comment: (lldb) po NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGAffineTransform([[pinch view] transform]))
error: no known method '-transform'; cast the message send to the method's return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression

Comment: Please verify on side first. I tried regular ways and transform just not work.

Comment: you mean on the live lldb it works? On my side, it does not. Attension, I am talking about live lldb, not code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77696/discussion-between-nilesh-patel-and-wingzero).

Answer (score 3):

This will print raw data of sender(UIPinchGestureRecognizer)

```
p (CGAffineTransform) [sender.view transform]
```

Just replace the view to yours

[image]

Comment: (lldb) p (CGAffineTransform) [[pinch view] transform]
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: I have tried, I post the screen shot.I do not know why in your XCode, it can not work

Comment: are you using simulator? I tried with simulator, it works, but on iPhone, no

Answer (score 0):

You can send `-bounds` to your UIView instance:

```
po [0x11d925730 bounds]
<CALayer:0x2811e64e0; position = CGPoint (187.5 420.5); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 375 589); delegate = <UIView: 0x11d925730; frame = (0 126; 375 589); layer = <CALayer: 0x2811e64e0>>; opaque = YES; allowsGroupOpacity = YES; transform = CATransform3D (1 0 0 0; 0 1 0 0; 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1); frame = (0 126; 375 589); layer = <CALayer: 0x2811e64e0>>>
```